# How does an application recognizes a security token from the identity provider?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, identity, provider

When there is a trust relation between the application and the issuer or the identity provider, what is the way in which this application recognizes that security token is from the issuer only?
Is thereby is some information in the token along with the claims or is it defined initially when we create a identity provider in an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both: the RP (the application) has a list of "trusted issuers" (the STS) and the token is digitally signed by the STS. The integrity of the token is verified in the app against the list that has been configured previously.

If an un-compromised token is received by the app, but it is coming from an issuer not in the list, it will be rejected.

There are other validations too (realm, audienceUri).

Also, "trust" is one way, but generally has to be configured on both ends.